# Elegant way to automate the call to setWindowsHookEx when a specific application is started

Tags: c++, winapi, process, hook, setwindowshookex

What would be the best way to automate the following Scenario.

Currently, I am hooking some method into
a process (example calculator process) for listening to some mouse events on that application. This is achieved by calling `setWindowsHookEx`
by some `exe`. For testing purpose, I run this `exe` through the command line or manually clicking it. Then `setWindowsHookEx` 
will automatically hook some method into the process( example calculator process). For this to work, calculator process
has to be running.

I am looking for a way to automate this Scenario. Which means when the calculator process is started, 
`exe` would be run automatically, thereby injecting the hook method into calculator process.

One solution I thought was , using windows service, which will monitor for all process creation in windows operating system and whenever calculator process opens, it will call `setwindowshookex`. Is there
other better way to achieve this. Thanks in advance for any thought on this

Comment: Another way in my opinion is to run the hook exe when Windows starts. It can have a tray icon for instance (if needed).

Comment: There is nothing very elegant about SetWindowsHookEx, this starts at -100 points.  But if you don't set the 4th argument then every process gets hooked.  Including ones you start later.  So you could check in the hook callback that the expected process got hooked, do nothing if it wasn't.

Comment: The Microsoft Application Compatibility Toolkit can load a specified DLL into a particular executable whenever it is started.  That might be an alternative to having a separate executable.

Comment: Why don't you ask about the problem you are trying to solve, rather than your proposed solution? This really sounds like you are looking for [WinEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373889.aspx) and [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx).